# Django admin output extra HTML in ModelSite

Tags: django, django-admin

Ultimately, I want to add an `<iframe>` to the display of a particular model on Django's admin page.  Django is already rendering the form for this model correctly, but I want to add this `<iframe>` in addition to Django's form.  The `src` attribute needs to involve the primary key for the currently-displayed record.

I've learned how to properly override the `change_form.html` template through Django's documentation, and I can add markup to the right block, but I can't figure out how to access the primary key value.  (No amount of determined Googling has helped at all.)

Alternatively, is there a direct way to specify that I want to produce extra output in my `ModelSite` definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overriding "change_form.html" is the right way to go. You can access the current object with

```
{{ original }}
```